# Ajuda com parâmetros em jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu passar um parâmetro com um valor obtido na query do relatório pai para um subrelatório, e usar este valor la no subrelatório...

:D

Comment: Você deve adicionar mais detalhes à sua pergunta,como informar a estrutura dos reports, indcar o parâmetro que está querendo passar. As perguntas precisam possuir um conteúdo verificável.

Comment: A situação é a seguinte...
Eu tenho um relatório em que no titulo exibe algumas informações vindas do banco, e no detail tenho um subreport para exibir alguns dados específicos.
A query q eu estou usando para exibir os dados no titulo do relatório me traz uma informação que gostaria de usar dentro do subreport, pra isso eu poderia incluir o valor dessa informação em um parâmetro, passar esse parâmetro para o subreport e usar esta informação dentro do meu subreport? para não precisar incluir esta tabela na query do subreport, pois já é usada na query do titulo no relatório pai.